# Use newly generated API Key from Powershell in Octopus Deploy

Tags: powershell, api-key, octopus-deploy

I am generating a new API Key with the following Powershell script:

```
function CreateAPIKey{
    Param(
        $OctopusURL,
        $APIKey,
        $UserName,
        $APIKeyPurpose,
        $NewAPIKey
    )
    ##PROCESS
    $header = @{ "X-Octopus-ApiKey" = $APIKey }

    $body = @{
        Purpose = $APIKeyPurpose
    } | ConvertTo-Json

    #Getting all users to filter target user by name
    $allUsers = (Invoke-WebRequest "$OctopusURL/api/users/all" -Headers $header -Method Get -UseBasicParsing).content | ConvertFrom-Json

    #Getting user that owns API Key that will be deleted
    $User = $allUsers | where{$_.username -eq $UserName}

    #Creating API Key
    $CreateAPIKeyResponse = (Invoke-WebRequest "$OctopusURL/api/users/$($User.id)/apikeys" -Method Post -Headers $header -Body $body -UseBasicParsing -Verbose).content | ConvertFrom-Json

    #Printing new API Key
    $NewAPIKey = $($CreateAPIKeyResponse.apikey)
    Write-output "API Key created: $($CreateAPIKeyResponse.apikey)"
}

CreateAPIKey $OctopusURL $APIKey $UserName $APIKeyPurpose $NewAPIKey
```

The script works fine and creates a new api key when I run it from Octopus Deploy. I am then setting up project in Octopus where I want to send an email to myself with the user name and new API Key. I have setup variables where the Username is hardcoded and displays in the email fine. But I dont know what value to assign $NewAPIKey as seen below.

[image]

When I recieve the email all I get is the #{NewAPIKey} where the APIKey should be.

Comment: What email? You code sample doesn't include any code to send an email?

Comment: I am not sending the email in the script. I have a send email step setup in Octopus where I can set variables and pop them into my email step.

Comment: I import the powershell script as a package in Octopus.

Comment: Assigning a value to a script variable in an Octopus “powershell script” step doesn’t automatically update the values of Project Variables for later steps, so your email step doesn’t know what the api key value is from your “generate api key” step. You should have a read about “output variables” https://octopus.com/docs/projects/variables/output-variables for how to pass values from one step to a later step. This still won’t update the values of predefined project variables though...